# How to run Ipython using Paramiko

Tags: python, ipython, paramiko

I have written a script that I need to access variables from a remote server using Paramiko.

Is it possible to access remote script object(s) just like running ipython on that server?

local ...
e.g. from foo.py

```
list = [1,2,3]

ipython -i foo.py

In[1]: list
Out[1] [1,2,3]
```

How can I access the same thing using Paramiko?
remote ..

```
ssh = ssh.exec_command('ipython -i /some path/foo.py')
```

Comment: I tried, I need to access the contents of the 'list' and use them.At the moment I can only access stdout(s) but that is not all I want.

Comment: Do you want to be able to control the remote IPython using your keyboard, or programmatically?

Comment: Infact I have a Django app running on local server.One funtion in my views.py needs data which can only be provided by running a remote script, I want to access values from those variables so that I can update my databases.Programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [RPyC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It allows accessing remote objects easily.

However, if you must use Paramiko, you can use the following example:

```
sin, sout, serr = ssh.exec_command("python")
sin.write('''x=["a1","b2","c3"]
print("-".join(x))
exit()
''')
sin.flush()
sin.channel.shutdown_write()
line = sout.readline()
print("line:{}".format(line))
myarr = line.split("-")
for e, i in enumerate(myarr):
    print("item {}:{}".format(e,i))
```

The output of which will be:

```
line:a1-b2-c3

item 0:a1
item 1:b2
item 2:c3
```

This means that your remote script must print the variable (to stdout) in order for you to read it, and you'll need to manipulate the output. Don't forget to clean up (close the pipes and the connection).

Comment: Thank you, I end up printing the variables and read to stdout.